# Discrepancy of the state of `numpy.random` disappears

Tags: python, numpy-random

There are two python runs of the same project with different settings, but with the same random seeds.

The project contains a function that returns a couple of random numbers using `numpy.random.uniform`.

Regardless of other uses of `numpy.random` in the python process, series of the function calls in both of the runs generate the same sequences, until some point.

And after generating different results for one time at that point, they generate the same sequences again, for some period.

I haven't tried using `numpy.random.RandomState` yet, but how is this possible?

Is it just a coincidence that somewhere something which uses `numpy.random` caused the discrepancy and fixed it again?

I'm curious if it is the only possibility or there is another explanation.

Thanks in advance.

ADD: I forgot to mention that there was no seeding at that point.

Comment: Without code, who knows? They're clearly not making the same exact sequence of calls, although it seems they're making the same *number* of calls. My guess would be on something being sensitive to hash ordering, but I've got no data to work with.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible, minimal example? Going to be really hard to give meaningful suggestions without specific implementation details.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It's actually kind of a huge project, and I wanted to rule out other possibilities. I was thinking that it would be easier to debug if I can hook `numpy.random`-related calls.

Comment: Does each separate run use the same number of calls to *any* `random` function? Or do you have some other random numbers being generated that depend on the settings of that run?

Comment: @AndrewGuy They use different numbers of calls eventually (not at first). I guess I can't interpret it another way. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `random` module in numpy, each randomly generated number (regardless of the distribution/function) uses the same "global" instance of `RandomState`. When you set the seed using `numpy.random.seed()`, you set the seed of the 'global' instance of `RandomState`. This is the same principle as the `random` library in Python.

I'm not sure of the specific implementation of the numpy random functions, but I suspect that each random function will make the underlying Mersenne Twister advance a number of 'steps', with the number of steps not necessarily being the same between different `random` functions.

So, if the order of *every* call to a `random` function is not the same between separate runs, then you may see divergence in the generated sequence of random numbers, with convergence again if the Mersenne Twister 'steps' line up again.

You could get around this by initialising a separate `RandomState` instance for each function you are using. For example:

```
import numpy as np

seed = 12345
r_uniform = np.random.RandomState(seed)
r_randint = np.random.RandomState(seed)

a_random_uniform_number = r_uniform.uniform()
a_random_int = r_randint.randint(10)
```

You might want to set different seeds for each instance - this will depend on what you are using these pseudo-random numbers for.

Comment: Thank you for answering. And yeah, it seems like there are no other ways to explain it.

Comment: @noname Yep, I would recommend always initialising your own `RandomState` instance. I've come across issues with multiple imported packages using `import random`, and then if one of those packages (or your own code) sets a seed, then *all* the packages end up with a seeded random instance.